# Virtual Keyboard only shows after two taps

Tags: android, keyboard, webview, virtual-keyboard

I have an app that has only one Webview and some buttons. On the webview I show a website that contains one textbox.

Sometimes, when I tap the textbox the virtual keyboard does not show, and I have to tap again. This only happens on OS 2.1

Has anyone else faced this? Anyone have any idea of what may be causing it?

I tryied removing focus, requesting focus, invalidating the screen, etc...

Please, any sugestions, or battle plans on how to defeat this bug would be greatly appreciated (Really, this bug is very annoying)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the area your text box is in has a onMouseOver event.  This would cause the first touch to activate that event and the second touch to activate the keyboard.

I see this all the time on my iPhone browser.

Comment: Hum, that actually makes sense... do you know if there is any way I can work around it?